# Cancel SAS Remote server process

Tags: sas

Using SAS 9.4, what's the best way to (or is it possible to) cancel a submitted statement that you have used `rsubmit` to submit to a remote server? I have tried the usual click "Break" > "Cancel Submitted Statements" but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Worth mentioning that your DBA's may be able to provide a solution as well. At my place of employment, a tool was made where you can see queries(submissions to the DB) actively running on your server, and gives you options to kill....

Comment: This is much easier to handle if you're using Enterprise Guide to connect to a remote server, if that's an option rather than using RSUBMIT.

Comment: This problem has been huge for me as well in the past. I've had processes stuck open for days. Usually I'll close out any SAS programs I have running, call up the admin and ask them to kill any sas.exe's running under my username. I generally only see it happen if EG crashes on me, or something goes wrong with a query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the "CONNECT" options when you select your "!" button. This will give you an option to cancel remote submissions.

[image: Cancel Prompt]

Comment: That's great but it also breaks my connection to the server but I just want to cancel the job.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no straightforward way of doing what you want. The remote server session will not respond to any further input from your local session until it has finished processing. All you can do is abandon the connection or kill the remote SAS process.

If this is happening to you frequently, I suggest you focus on making your remote sessions abort at the first sign of any trouble, e.g. by setting `option errorabend`, or have your remote code regularly check for the presence of a 'canary' file that you can delete if you want to regain control.

To avoid having to get your server admins involved every time this happens, perhaps you could also set up a script as part of the remote server autoexec.sas file to kill all orphan processes running in your name each time you connect to a new remote session.